# Unicode to UTF-8 encoding issue when importing SQL text file into MySQL

Tags: python, mysql, unicode, encoding, utf-8

Here's the scenario:

I have a url in a MySQL database that contains Unicode. The database uses the Latin-1 encoding. Now, when I read the record from MySQL using Python, it gets converted to Unicode because all strings follow the Unicode format in Python.

I want to write the URL into a text file -- to do so, it needs to be converted to bytes (UTF-8). This was done successfully.

Now, given the URLS that are in the text file, I want to query the db for these SAME urls in the database. I do so by calling the source command to execute a few select queries.

Result: I get no matches.

I suspect that the problem stems from my conversion to UTF-8, which somehow is messing up the symbols.

Comment: Post your effort so we can find out where the problem lies.

Comment: It's definitely the encoding. It seems that when I encode it in UTF-8, one of the unicode symbols got converted to a question mark. This is screwing up the query. How can I get MySQL to interpret it as unicode????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You most probably need to set your mysql shell client to use utf8.

You can set it either in mysql shell directly by running `set character set utf8`.
Or by adding `default-character-set=utf8` to your `~/.my.cnf`.